# Pass NSString to PHP script

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, post

I currently have the following code

```
-(void)returnToSQL
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://babyfood.30ptdesign.com\....php"];

    NSData *dataUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",strResult);
}
```

I need to pass an `NSString` named `_username` into a variable of the same name in the PHP file, without using `ASIFormDataRequest`.

Is there any way to do this?  I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: Look into NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection and be sure to read up on GET and POST requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your php with parameters.

Something like this

```
http://domain/file.php?param=string
```

and in your php

```
<?php
  $param = $_GET['param'];
  echo $param;
?>
```

Comment: This works perfectly for the first variable, thanks!  How can I add a second variable on?  Ie.  http://domain/file.php?param1=string1?param2=string2 does not work.  How would I write that?

Comment: There are possibilities to do so. However I didn't try that myself but it should be something like this:
    http:// domain/test.php?param1=param1&param2=param2&param3=param3
Always remember to avoid sql injection when using with databases! There are several tutorials out there! :)